# can't enter django chartit formatter field

Tags: javascript, python, django, charts, highcharts

I'm working on a django project and decided to add charts to some of the pages. I chose Chartit for the task.

The problem is that I want to make the axis labels and the tooltip have custom format, and I'd like to use the Highcharts' formatter field for that job.

For example, I'm trying to make the Y-axis labels show as precents. Doing so in the following way:

```
chart_options=
            {
                'title': {'text':''},
                'yAxis': {
                           'min':0,
                    'labels': {
                        'formatter': '''function(){
                                        var pcnt = this.value  * 100;
                                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + "%"; 
                                        }'''
                               }
                          }    

              }
```

When doing it so, I get the following error message when refreshing the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function(){
                                        var pcnt = this.value  * 100;
                                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + "%"; 
                                        } has no method 'call'
```

So I tried writing the javascript function in my html template, and send its name in the python code in the following way:

```
#chart_options in views.py
'formatter': 'precentor'

#html template:
<script type="text/javascript">
function precentor(){
    var pcnt = this.value  * 100;
    return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%'; 
}
</script>
```

But I got same error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Object precentor has no method 'call'

What should I do to make those functions "callable"

Comment: Have you tried to use: `'formatter': precentor` so precentor will be variable?

Comment: @PawełFus Yes. If I won't define a python function with that name I get a "NameError: global name 'precentor' is not defined".
If I do declare such function I get a "TypeError: <function precentor at 0x0000000003C69898> is not JSON serializable", and I can't understand how to serialize a python function using simplejson or such..

Comment: JSON can't have functions :) But solution with `'formatter': precentor` should work, if percentor will be defined as global variable.

Comment: @PawełFus Please remember its a python code. Writing the function name without apostrophes around it will cause the python interpreter to look for a variable/function named "precentor".

Comment: I'm not so good with python, but how do you use: `setInterval( myFunction, 1000)`? Where myFunction is defined as javascript function.

Comment: @PawełFus If I knew I would have make my program work :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope these links will help you to figure out the issue -

jsfiddle sample for `xAxis` and `yAxis` - http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-formatter-linked/

API documentation about the `formater` callback method - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter

Without having your test environment I can't test it for your exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this, where you want to call a js function from django code (e.g. formatter) you can follow a different technique and **do not use chartit but use highcharts.js library** directly from template.

You can check this old example https://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2011/08/30/highcharts-django-admin/